# Display results from Rserve in Java (Integration of R and Java)

Tags: java, r, rserve

I'm integrating R with Java using Rserve. By using

```
REXP r = c.eval("median(1:4)");
```

I can get the correct result of 2.5.

But when I used a new set of data which had more than 1 result to show, I only got the first result. For example:

```
REXP w = c.eval("quantile (x, c(.01, .05, .1, .25, .5, .75, .9, .95, .99))");
System.out.println(w.asString());
```

I expect to get something like

```
 5.050  5.250  5.500  6.250  8.500 10.375 10.750 10.875 10.975
```

But I only got

```
5.050
```

Please help me with that. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
double[] quants = c.eval("quantile (x, c(.01, .05, .1, .25, .5, .75, .9, .95, .99))").asDoubles();
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(quants));
```

Comment: No worries, appreciate the enthusiasm :)